# In OverLeaf, my Bibliography is not the same as my bib files

Tags: bibtex

Here is the link of my file! https://www.overleaf.com/read/qnjpdtmjsvpd
please help me!

Here are my ref.bib file, here is my code:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{refs}
```

---

```
@article{turing:1,
  title={A survey of robot learning from demonstration},
  author={Argall, Brenna D and Chernova, Sonia and Veloso, Manuela and Browning, Brett},
  journal={Robotics and autonomous systems},
  volume={57},
  number={5},
  pages={469--483},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}


@article{turing:2,
  title={Robot learning from human teachers},
  author={Chernova, Sonia and Thomaz, Andrea L},
  journal={Synthesis lectures on artificial intelligence and machine learning},
  volume={8},
  number={3},
  pages={1--121},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Morgan \& Claypool Publishers}
}


@inproceedings{turing:3,
  title={Learning deep movement primitives using convolutional neural networks},
  author={Pervez, Affan and Mao, Yuecheng and Lee, Dongheui},
  booktitle={2017 IEEE-RAS 17th international conference on humanoid robotics (Humanoids)},
  pages={191--197},
  year={2017},
  organization={IEEE}
}


@inproceedings{turing:4,
  title={Imitation from observation: Learning to imitate behaviors from raw video via context translation},
  author={Liu, YuXuan and Gupta, Abhishek and Abbeel, Pieter and Levine, Sergey},
  booktitle={2018 IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA)},
  pages={1118--1125},
  year={2018},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

Here is the coming out Bibliography
[1] Kunjal Ahir, Kajal Govani, Rutvik Gajera, and Manan Shah. Application on virtual reality for
enhanced education learning, military training and sports. Augmented Human Research, 5:1–9,
2020.

[2] Florence A ̈ım, Guillaume Lonjon, Didier Hannouche, and Remy Nizard. Effectiveness of virtual
reality training in orthopaedic surgery. Arthroscopy: the journal of arthroscopic & related surgery,
32(1):224–232, 2016.

[3] C Anthes. Rj garc ıa-herna ndez, m. wiedemann, and d. kranzlmu ller,“state of the art of virtual
reality technology,”. In 2016 IEEE Aerospace Conference, pages 1–19.

[4] Brenna D Argall, Sonia Chernova, Manuela Veloso, and Brett Browning. A survey of robot learning
from demonstration. Robotics and autonomous systems, 57(5):469–483, 2009

as you can see, they are not the same paper, normaly it should be the same

Comment: i don't know why is is not working? is even not the same paper for the  Bibliography and my ref.bib file

Comment: latex never reads the bib file, and you tagged biblatex but you are using bibtex, not biblatex. Just entries that you `\cite` appear in the document unless you use `\nocite{*}` to include them all

Comment: I'm sorry i might not understand very clearly， So what code should i use? i do cite them all, but the result is not the same paper in my bib file, is some other papers

Comment: check if you have another ref.bib somewhere (or give your bib a better name).

Comment: this is my only ref.bib file, i have tried change another namel, but is not working, the problem is i can see my reference, but they are all wrong, is not the paper i wirte in the bib file

Comment: latex never makes up text and has no access to files outside your project or the standard texlive files. So any output you see is from your code, but you have not shown your code or your output and not shown any error message so it is impossible to help

Comment: if that file is `ref.bib` as you say, it will not be used as you are using `refs.bb` (with an `s`)  see:  `\bibliography{refs}`

Comment: I'm Sorry it is a mistake, the fact is that the file is named refs.bib, and my code is also \bibliography{refs}, but the reference comes out is wrong, i do not have other bib files, so that really confuse me

Comment: what do mean by "wrong"? How does it look like?

Comment: [1] Kunjal Ahir, Kajal Govani, Rutvik Gajera, and Manan Shah. Application on virtual reality for
enhanced education learning, military training and sports. Augmented Human Research, 5:1–9,
2020.

Comment: this is the first reference, bu the fact is in my refs.bib file, is not the same paper, the first paper should be :A survey of robot learning from demonstration

Comment: i'm sorry, i new to this web, how should i uplod my origional file?

Comment: Is your issue with how the bibliography is sorted? How should they be sorted? This will depend on the bibliography style.

Comment: My problem is that I write my own refs.bib file, but when I use it, the document that comes out is not the same thing that I cite in the bib file, for example, I cite document A, but it shows a completely unrelated document B

Comment: Hi! i just upload my file link!  it wouold be really helpful if you could have a look, to be honest i a new to this web and latex, i really don't know where is the bug

Comment: The only part you need to look at is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPS5Q.png) if you have _any_ error any pdf output is not intended to be usable, and you have  16  fix them before worrying about the output

Comment: your log says `I found no \citation commands---while reading file output.aux
Database file #1: refs.bib
You've used 0 entries,` you have no `\cite` so have an empty bibliography, add `\nocite{*}` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: I finally solve the problem! it is because the code school provide is \bibliographystyle{plain}, it might cover my code, after i change the style, it all works, i t will generate the correct reference.   thanks all your guys help, especially "David Carlisle","Ulrike Fischer"